# How to access folder without domain and with ip address at WHM Web Host Manager?

Tags: cpanel, whm

I have root access, but I do not have domain name. I want to upload project and access through IP address. How is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

That would be possible. Enable mod_userdir in WHM -> Apache mod_userdir Tweak. If userdir protection is enabled them uncheck the protection for the desired cpaneluser and also for the user nobody.

Then access your account like http://server-ip/~cpanelusername

Answer (score 0):

In Windows system hosts files are located in Windows – SystemRoot > system32 > drivers > etc > hosts
By default, the system root is C:Windows, so if you are using Windows, your host's file is most probably: C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

In Linux system hosts files are located in Linux – /etc/hosts

In Mac system hosts files are located in Mac OS X – /private/etc/hosts

For more details please check the link

https://www.blazingcoders.com/how-to-access-hosted-website-files-without-domain-name-or-domain-control